# Regulate FAN voltage from another potentiometer (Different voltages)

Tags: voltage, fan, speed

Currently i have a 100w LED been powered from a 14.4V lipo battery. I use a Voltage Booster to boost voltage up to 33V. I have modified the voltage booster with a pararel potentiometer to change LED intensivity on the go (From 24V to 33V)
[image: Voltage Booster]

Also i have a 12V fan to heatsink and i use a step down buck converter to lower and regulate voltage to 12V. Now i want to reuse my installed potentiometer to regulate fan voltage and LED at same time without the need of having 2 potentiometer. Since potentiomter is receiving a different voltage from LED how can i wire the hardware to make it work?

- LED Min Voltage from POT: 24V
- LED Max Voltage from POT: 33V
- Desired Fan Min Voltage from POT: 8V
- Desired Fan Max Voltage from POT: 12V

[image: Buck Converter]

[image: Voltage Booster Pot]

Last image shows my configuration for the potentiometer and voltage booster

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your "Last image"... I guess this is your setup:

[image]

Both voltage converters share the same ground.

As @Peter said, without knowing the schematic design of your converters, the safest way is to use a dual potentiometer.

If you really want to use single potentiometer, it may be possible to wire it to bias two transistors. Again, without knowing what devices you have it is impossible to tell exactly. To make an idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX8qw7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, thats my setup, plus the pot for LED. I use generic modules from eBay so i guess i should buy stereo pot. i Just have a 50K stereo in home and i guess that value to high and will turn off LED at max resistor

Answer (score 0):

Safest way is to use a dual ("stereo") pot, with one section controlling each supply.

You cannot safely use a single pot to control the two supplies unless you know the design of the two circuits, an can verify that the two control inputs can be safely connected together.

Comment: I go check if i have any from old TV MB's. But will be a pain to change the hardware because is already installed in a small case. Still there are any other easy option? like use some diode and resistors?